# From Git to SVN

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, bitbucket, git-svn

I actually have a repository on Bitbucket, and i would like to migrate to an SVN system. Most of the guides on the net are from SVN to GIT, very few guidelines on the inverse.

I've been using tortoise SVN, and tried a couple of stuffs like :

```
1. cd /path/to/git/localrepo
2. svn mkdir --parents protocol:///path/to/repo/PROJECT/trunk -m "Importing git repo"
3. git svn init protocol:///path/to/repo/PROJECT -s
4. git svn fetch
5. git rebase trunk
5.1  git status
5.2  git add (conflicted-files)
5.3  git rebase --continue
5.4.  (repeat 5.1.)
6. git svn dcommit
```

Always crashes to errors. Anyone has a better idea on how to do it?

Comment: So what are these errors?

Comment: @UweKeim Can't create session : Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///D:%5CRepositoryTest' : Unable to open repository 'file:///D:%CRepositoryTest' at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm at line 310

Comment: It crashes when I execute the third step ;  git svn init protocol:///path/to/repo/PROJECT -s @UweKeim

Answer (score 0):

As your comment says `file:///D:%5CRepositoryTest` and `%5C` is the URL encoding of `\`, I'd say you do `git svn init file:///D:\RepositoryTest -s` where you should do `git svn init file:///D:/RepositoryTest -s`.